# How to filter json on url?

Tags: php, json

How can I filter the json data from database on a certain field?

Here is my json

```
[
    {
        "Car_No":"25",
        "Car_Model":"car1",
        "Car_Type":"car2",
        "Capacity":"12",
        "Image":"carkila.esy.es\/upload\/20160811031546.png",
        "fuelType":"Diesel",
        "carPlatenuNumber":"qwe - 123",
        "carStatus":null,
        "owner":"owner"
    },
    {
        "Car_No":"24",
        "Car_Model":"car",
        "Car_Type":"car2",
        "Capacity":"123",
        "Image":"carkila.esy.es\/upload\/20160808114541.png",
        "fuelType":"Biofuels (biodiesel and bioethanol)",
        "carPlatenuNumber":"qwe - 123",
        "carStatus":null,
        "owner":"owner"
    },
    {
        "Car_No":"23",
        "Car_Model":"fortuner",
        "Car_Type":"suv",
        "Capacity":"56",
        "Image":"carkila.esy.es\/upload\/20160805104115.png",
        "fuelType":"Super unleaded petrol",
        "carPlatenuNumber":"xxx888",
        "carStatus":null,
        "owner":"owner"
    },
    {
        "Car_No":"22",
        "Car_Model":"seannnn",
        "Car_Type":"seanyboy",
        "Capacity":"12",
        "Image":"carkila.esy.es\/upload\/20160805091944.png",
        "fuelType":"Biofuels (biodiesel and bioethanol)",
        "carPlatenuNumber":"hjk123",
        "carStatus":null,
        "owner":"sean"
    },
    {
        "Car_No":"21",
        "Car_Model":"cars",
        "Car_Type":"car1",
        "Capacity":"12",
        "Image":"carkila.esy.es\/upload\/20160805091429.png",
        "fuelType":"Premium unleaded",
        "carPlatenuNumber":"qwe321",
        "carStatus":null,
        "owner":"owner"
    },
    {
        "Car_No":"20",
        "Car_Model":"car",
        "Car_Type":"car1",
        "Capacity":"123",
        "Image":"https:\/\/www.enterprise.ca\/content\/dam\/global-vehicle-images\/cars\/CHRY_200_2015.png",
        "fuelType":"Biofuels (biodiesel and bioethanol)",
        "carPlatenuNumber":"qwe123",
        "carStatus":null,
        "owner":"owner"
    }
]
```

I want it to be like `http://carkila.esy.es/user.php?owner=sean` and it will filter all the owner that has sean in it.

here is my json conversion code.

```
<?PHP
include_once("connection.php");

session_start();

$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_cars ORDER BY Car_No DESC"; 

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Thanks guys :)

Comment: modify the query accordingly using a `WHERE` clause

Comment: @Ghost -  It'll work also but I wanted it to be on the url would that be possible? Because I need the url filtering ones on my android code.

Comment: supply criteria inside where clause based on query string in url

Comment: @Ghost - But I dont want it to be on the query. I want it to be on the url because it will be based on who will log in sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?PHP
include_once("connection.php");

session_start();

$where = ''
if (isset($_GET['owner'])){
  $where = " WHERE owner like '%".addslashes($_GET['owner'])."%'";
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_cars ".$where." ORDER BY Car_No DESC"; 

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to filter the dataset based on a request to your JSON conversion script with the query string containing `owner`, I suggest using the database to filter out the result set, rather than filtering out the data after it's been iterated over already.

**user.php?owner=sean**

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/connection.php';

session_start();
$owner = isset($_GET['owner']) ? $_GET['owner'] : null;
$query = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_cars';
if (isset($owner)) {
   $query .=  ' WHERE owner = ?';
}
$query .= ' ORDER BY Car_No DESC';
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query); 
if (isset($owner)) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $owner); 
}
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$data = array();
if ($result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

If you're looking for owners that contains the word `sean` replace the `WHERE` statement with.

```
$query .= ' WHERE owner LIKE ?';
```

and replace `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` with

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', '%' . $owner . '%');
```

**Result:**

```
[
    {
        "Car_No":"22",
        "Car_Model":"seannnn",
        "Car_Type":"seanyboy",
        "Capacity":"12",
        "Image":"carkila.esy.es\/upload\/20160805091944.png",
        "fuelType":"Biofuels (biodiesel and bioethanol)",
        "carPlatenuNumber":"hjk123",
        "carStatus":null,
        "owner":"sean"
    }
]
```